# How do I make a column/vector that orders rows sequentially based on another vector's identity. R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, seq, genome

I have a dataframe that has all exons and the gene the exon belongs to.
The current exon names are not indicative of their order.
I have ordered them based on the starting genomic position,
so now I just need to generate a column that gives them an order number according to the gene.

Example of that top of the dataframe:

GENE          EXON

GENE1,       "789",
GENE1,       "953",
GENE1,       "102",
GENE2,       "43024",
GENE3,       "542",
GENE3,       "047",

So this is what I want my data frame to look like:

GENE          EXON    genomic order

GENE1,       "789",     1

GENE1,       "953",     2

GENE1,       "102",     3

GENE2,       "43024",   1

GENE3,       "542",     1

GENE3,       "047",     2

How do I make a column that orders rows sequentially based on another vector's identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below with `ave`

```
transform(df, Order = ave(1:nrow(df),GENE,FUN = seq_along))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Order :=  rowid(GENE)]
```